# Can I use CollectionViewSource in my viewmodel on MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, collectionview

I'm developing an application with MVVM.  I have 2 separate projects for this, one for my view and another for viewmodel.

Now, a part of a application requires `Filtering` and `Sorting` feature over the `Collection`

I started searching how to do this with MVVM and it seems like most of pages which I went through referring me to go with `CollectionViewSource` in viewmodel.  However, it requires `PresentationFramework` as reference to my viewmodel project which is WPF specific assembly.

Is it ok to have `PresentationFramework` reference in my viewmodel.  If not, whats is the correct way of doing this?

**Note:** I'm thinking for exposing `ObservableCollection` from VM and do all the stuffs like `Sorting` in view itself with the help of `CollectionView`. Am I right in this way?

Comment: I've done it, but I think you're right in that it's breaking the independence of ViewModels. I wonder if you could build the CollectionViewSource  in the View, or use a converter?

Comment: @Joe . . Yup,  planning to have it in view itself. `converters` wont work for what I need I think.

Comment: You could grab the ViewModel when the DataContext is changed

Comment: There has been a lot of discussion around this topic here on StackOverflow, and the answer to your question is entirely opinion-based. My opinion: as long as you're not intending to reuse the view model in a non-WPF application, there is no reason at all why you should not use types from WPF assemblies.